# go to next page didn't work (by HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, htmlunit

following codes are written to click on "Next Button" in a HTML page and open new pages and get data of each page:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        String url = "http://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?1=&2=&3=&4=-1&5=%d8%af%d8%b9%d9%88%d8%aa&6=&7=&8=-1&9=-1&10=-1&11=&12=False&13=0";
        WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL(url));
        webRequest.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        for (int page_counter = 0; page_counter < number_of_codal_pages_for_going_back; page_counter++) {
            HtmlTable html_table = page.getHtmlElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvList");
            for (int i_h_table_row = html_table.getRowCount() - 1; i_h_table_row > 0; i_h_table_row--) {
                final HtmlTableRow html_row = html_table.getRow(i_h_table_row);
                String ticker = html_row.getCell(0).asText();
                System.out.println(ticker);
            }
            System.out.println("______________________________");
            HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("aspnetForm");
            HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPager1$btnNext");
            page = button.click();
        }
    }
```

But whatever it prints are repeated (are same as the first page) and seems program can't go to the next page.

why?

thanks.

Comment: real Firefox works good.

Comment: the button I want to click on it is: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPager1$btnNext" value="" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPager1_btnNext" title="بعدی" class="normal gridpagernext" />

Comment: You have disabled logging at all and setThrowExceptionOnScriptError also. If you like to find the cause of a problem this is not the best approach.

Comment: @RBRi  - thanks - but if i enable these, the program won't work at all. I mean even the first page contents will not be printed (also the other pages). it gives me this error:

Comment: @RBRi and this exception:  com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: **illegal character** (http://codal.ir/js/Common.js#1)

Comment: @asashour salaam; could you please solve the problem.

Comment: Most of your stuff is just a warning: DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING, if you like you can save the css and open a CSSParser issue. Will have a look then. But so far you can ignore this.

Comment: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: illegal character This is a real problen. But this is fixed already. Use the latest snapshot build.

Comment: @RBRi ----------- https://a.uguu.se/N7KqqMwXJYh4_exceptions_report.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This works with the latest SNAPSHOT

```
        try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        String url = "http://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?1=&2=&3=&4=-1&5=%d8%af%d8%b9%d9%88%d8%aa&6=&7=&8=-1&9=-1&10=-1&11=&12=False&13=0";

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        System.out.println("______________________________");
        System.out.println(page.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPager1_gridpager").asXml());
        System.out.println("______________________________");

        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("aspnetForm");
        HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPager1$btnNext");
        page = button.click();

        System.out.println("______________________________");
        System.out.println(page.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPager1_gridpager").asXml());
        System.out.println("______________________________");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @RBRi, thanks for your help. I gave **htmlunit-2.28-SNAPSHOT.jar (2.35 MB)** from this [link](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts#!-co8lurqzvuq9,-osh216zawhyd) and add it to libraries. but  it gave me this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider` from first line (`try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {`) .    I'm amateur in java and htmlunit so there may be a problem from me. everything is bad and I'm realy upset :(

Comment: Use the zip and replace all you libs with the recent ones.

Comment: Hi @rbri, it's about one day I'm working on these... but problem still exist... there are two zip file. one is **htmlunit-2.28-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip** and another is **htmlunit-2.28-SNAPSHOT-src.zip** I added them as library (one by one and then together) but got this exception: `Uncompilable source code - package com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit does not exist` [look at this picture](https://vgy.me/Qu4313.png) . and if i add all of them together I will get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` ([look here](https://vgy.me/718k7F.png))

Comment: perhaps download link was not right. it was: canoo->htmlunit->fastbuild-> #3068 (29 Jun 17 18:46) -> artifacts

Comment: in version 2.27 the problem is (I think) from java_script. I add a code for saving the page by `page.save(file_a);` then after the code: `page=button.click()` I save another page by `page.save(file_b);` in the output I see only some part of page had changed. compare [picture_a](https://vgy.me/39ivhX.png) VS [picture_b](https://vgy.me/8HxnzN.png) .the exception is `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: illegal character (http://codal.ir/js/Common.js#1)`

Comment: You need htmlunit-2.28-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip; this is a zip archive, you have to unpack it locally and than replace your libs with the ones from the lib folder.

Comment: thank you dear @RBRi for your help. but problem didn't solve. I have extracted jars as you told and put them in library. [this picture.](https://vgy.me/4Z1cFU.png) but still the program can't go to the next page. and still there is JavaScript exception. it says: `SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: :x).]`  I copy all output and code here in [this TXT file](https://gist.github.com/322d246a9e2af8f07c4942257ca4d50f) if you want to see.

Comment: if you have problem seeing utf chars of Persian/Arabic language I changed the codes. here it is : [(codes_text)](https://gist.github.com/71c731bd08a760b8807fee08d0e11346)---------------------------you can see that (numbers should all update but) only one part of page updates!  and the program **can't go to the third page!** (however it can go to the second page!) - I think the problem is from htmlUnit... not from my codes.